# WebStorm refresh file metadata after renaming

Tags: webstorm

In WebStorm (2020.2.2) I accidentally named a file `foo.jss` and I renamed the file name to `.js` but WebStorm has not recognized the change. I already removed my `.idea` folder.

I appreciate any help or hint.

[image]

Comment: Does it display correctly in Terminal or Finder/Explorer?

Comment: 1) Focus the file in the Project View (just like you have on your screenshot) 2) Now invoke `View | Quick Documentation` -- it will show some popup with file info. The info you are after is the File Type (how IDE treats this file). I have no clue what the file type might be .. as it shows WebStorm's icon (never seen that before)

Comment: 3) Now go to the `Settings/Preferences | File Types`, locate that file type in the top list, look in the middle list (patterns) and remove unwanted pattern (will be similar to the original file name before the rename). If pattern is not there .. then we need to look into config files. (*P.S.*, `.jss` extension stands for "JavaScript Style Sheets" -- see if that will help you)

Comment: @LazyOne It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Focus the file in the Project View (just like you have on your screenshot).
2. Now invoke `View | Quick Documentation`: IDE will show a popup with file info. The info you are after is the File Type (how IDE treats this file).

   *I cannot say what the file type might be as it shows WebStorm's icon (never seen that before)*... but `.jss` file extension usually stands for "JavaScript Style Sheet".
3. Now go to the `Settings/Preferences | File Types`, locate that file type in the top list, then look in the middle list (patterns) and remove such unwanted pattern (will be similar to the original file name before the rename).

   If it's not under that file type... then also look through other file types, "Files Opened In Associated Applications" entry in particular (the idea based on the WebStorm file icon).

If such unwanted pattern cannot be found under any of the file types for some reason... then we need to look into the actual config files where such info is stored.